# Running EJB 2.1 on Wildfly 10

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss

I want to run `EJB 2.1` with `Wildfly-10 AS`
I have a server running on `jBoss-EAP-6.2`
Following are the configuration xml files

**I wanna achieve to run a Web Module (JSF) with existing server (EJB 2.1) running on JBoss-EAP-6.2.**

Following are the ideas

1. I can run JSF on JBoss-EAP-6.2 (possible?) that can communicate with EJB within the server
2. Deploy JSF on wildfly and it communicate with EJB through JBoss-EAP-6.2

**MORE / FINDINGS**

1. while deploying JSF on JBoss-6, I am getting blank page on opening, noting is shown
2. Wildfly does not support CMP files of EJB 2.1

**The Idea**

We have a desktop based [swing] application running on JDK 1.7, EJB 2.1, JBoss-EAP-6.2. I want to enable/implement its web module [JSF]

I want to reuse its server [EJB].

My idea is to use EJB 2.1 with JSF on Wildfly or deploy JSF to connect EJB on JBoss-EAP-6.2.

Comment: Are you deploying a single EAR file containing a WAR and EJB jar file?

Comment: Application is running on swing [desktop application], its EJB are deployed separately as a jar files. I want to develop its web module. Idea is to deploy only web war, on deployed server

Comment: @SteveC updated

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to migrate from `EJB2.1` to new `EJB3.x`. I understand that it will be really a hard way, but it will be easier to extend this application further. Then you will be able to easily write your web module on `JSF` within `WildFly 10`.
2. Start new server instance of `WildFly 10` and try to use remote `EJB2.x` interfaces within it to access business logic. And then use it to build your web module.
3. Develop `REST` facade on top of your `EJB` on `jBoss-EAP` and then use it the way you want it.
4. Start writing from scratch with new technologies.

Comment: Migrating or writing from scratch is not recommended, as Application is up and running from years, It need time as well as money, On point 2 and 3 can you add some link on it, thanks

Comment: you can look here https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/EJB2.1_and_EJB3_references.html and also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051310/can-ejb2-and-ejb3-coexists-in-one-application on invoking ejb2.1 from ejb3. on the `REST` part try to find information on the internet. you just need new `REST` web services that will act as facade on your old `Jboss EAP` instance and then use it as client from standalone new `WildFly 10` instance