# Wildfly compatibility with EJB

Tags: jboss, wildfly, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x, ejb-2.x

I’m working on a migration project that woul change WebLogic application server soon to be off support to Wildfly 10.0.0.Final, the problem I’m facing is that the project was built with ejb 2.1 and I don’t know wether Wildfly 10.0.0 would be compatible or not ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you may need to rewrite things if need be, it's generally not that difficult I've been porting a lot of our apps from JBoss EAP 5.1 to 7.0 with only minor changes and troubleshooting - else, in this QandA someone offers a workaround with remote EJB 2.1 interfaces being called from EJB 3 [running ejb2.1 on wildfly 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44277030/running-ejb-2-1-on-wildfly-10)

Comment: If you can, pass this project as soon as possible to EJB 3.1.

Answer (score 3):

Your migration will be relatively easy ***unless*** your application makes use of CMP entity beans.

If you have more than around 3 or 4 of these then migration will get tricky as you would need to migrate the CMP beans to JPA.

Otherwise, most changes will revolve around moving to Java EE standard JNDI names